# Coping values to another workbook if matching text is found

Tags: excel, vba

The following code opens a .csv file, finds “Trimmed Mean” in col B, uses the row of “Trimmed Mean” as the starting point  to find the next “NC” value in column B and copies value one cell to the right of “NC” to the Workbook from which the code is executed (Sheet 1 col A).

The problem is that the code runs but the value is not copied to the sheet1.  It’s probably just a minor thing but I can’t figure out what that is. Thanks for your help.

```
Const delim = vbTab  'for TAB delimited text files


Sub ImportMultipleTextFiles()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sFile As Variant
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim varMyItem As String

varMyItem = "NC"

sFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.csv),*.csv", , "Please select text file...")

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sFile)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

wb.Sheets(1).Select

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Debug.Print "LastRow = " & LastRow

Set aCell = ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B" & LastRow).Find(What:="Trimmed Mean", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

Debug.Print "Trimmed Mean can be found in Row # " & aCell.Row
'wb.Sheets(1).Select

For Each rngCell In ActiveSheet.Range("B" & aCell.Row & ":B" & LastRow)
' Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Range("B" & aCell.Row & ":B" & LastRow)
    If InStr(rngCell, "NC") > 0 Then
        Debug.Print rngCell.Row
'
        rngCell.Offset(0, 1).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)

        Exit For
    End If
Next rngCell


wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

Set wb = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: stay **away** from `Select` and `ActiveSheet` in your code as much as possible (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)). Qualify all your `Workbooks / Sheets / Ranges` and your code will most likely run as smooth as you desire. This line, in particular, is a real problem: `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read my comment above and review the link I sent.

I have edited your code to qualify all your objects and work directly with each *intended* object. In this way you can be sure that your code will act on the **exact** object you desire every-time.

You can define the lines I edited, by the `'***` at the line's end.

```
Const delim = vbTab  'for TAB delimited text files

Sub ImportMultipleTextFiles()

Dim wb As Workbook, wbThis As Workbook '***
Dim wsCopy As Worksheet, wsPaste As Worksheet '***
Dim sFile As Variant
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim varMyItem As String

Set wbThis = ThisWorkbook '***
Set wsPaste = wbThis.Sheets("Sheet1") 'change name as needed '***

varMyItem = "NC"

sFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.csv),*.csv", , "Please select text file...")

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sFile)
Set wsCopy = wb.Sheets(1) '***

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

LastRow = wsCopy.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row '***
Debug.Print "LastRow = " & LastRow

Set aCell = wsCopy.Range("B1:B" & LastRow).Find(What:="Trimmed Mean", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) '***

Debug.Print "Trimmed Mean can be found in Row # " & aCell.Row
'wb.Sheets(1).Select '***

For Each rngCell In wsCopy.Range("B" & aCell.Row & ":B" & LastRow) '***
' Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Range("B" & aCell.Row & ":B" & LastRow)
    If InStr(rngCell, "NC") > 0 Then
        Debug.Print rngCell.Row
'
        rngCell.Offset(0, 1).Copy Destination:=wsPaste.Range("A" & wsPaste.Range("A" & wsPaste.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) '***

        Exit For
    End If
Next rngCell


wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

Set wb = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```